# Laravel 4.2 storage_path() returning null

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to get phpunit set up in my app but I get the following error when I try to run phpunit:

```
ErrorException: file_put_contents(/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It looks like the reason is because storage_path() is returning null and I have no idea why or how to intelligently fix it.  I did not develop this app so for all I know, the storage path could be rewritten to null(if this is even possible) manually without my knowing.  However, I can't find any evidence of this.

Comment: You should use relative paths in the `storage_path` function. not sure if that is the issue but: `storage_path('meta/services.json')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting... storage_path() is supposed to return the fully qualified path to the app/storage directory.  I don't think it accepts any arguments, but in any case, I need the absolute path for my purposes.  Also, the code that uses this method is in external libraries that I shouldn't really change.  I just need to know WHY this is returning null, not necessarily how to get it to return something else.